# Kotlin destructuring variables is not working with Pair, Triple or data class

Tags: java, kotlin, destructuring, data-class

I've recently tried the following code in kotlinc, command line environment.

```
var greet = Pair("Hello", "World")
val (word1, word2) = greet
```

Outputting `word1` and `word2` in console outputs the below message

```
>>> word1
error: unresolved reference: word1
word1
^
```

I'm not sure if de-structuring is being removed from the latest version of kotlin. Currently, using `1.0.2` version of `kotlinc` compiler on mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known limitation in the Kotlin REPL. Destructuring declarations work fine in the source code (.kt files).

Here's the issue in the bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5620

Comment: Is the issue resolved? I think not..Scratch files also not supporting deconstructing values I guess... giving same error unresolved reference.. Working fine with online Kotlin compiler now but not with scratch files till today..